# Does the opposite inequality of A.M ≥ G.M holds?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b>0$. Does there exists $C_1,C_2>0$ such that $a+b \leq C_1(ab)^{C_2}$ holds?

We know from A.M ≥ G.M that the opposite inequality holds for $C_1=2,C_2=½$

Comment: I think you mean $C_1=2$. Also, I believe you mean to ask: "do there exist $C_1,C_2>0$ such that for any $a,b>0$...". Of course for any given $a,b>0$ you can find $C_1,C_2>0$ that work. The question is do they work for *all* $a,b>0$.

Comment: By homogeneity such an inequality could only hold if $C_2=1/2$. But that cannot work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume such constants exist and then let $a\rightarrow 0$ then
$$b=\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}a+b\leq\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}C_1(ab)^{C_2}=0$$
Contradiction!